# Create and assign reference data from within a struct method

Tags: rust

I have abstracted my problem inside the following code:

```
struct List<'a> {
    attr: &'a String
}

impl<'a> List<'a> {
    fn new() -> List<'a> {
        let my_attr = "Something";
        List {
            attr: &my_attr.to_string()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    List::new();
}
```

It yields some notices and fails compiling claiming that the borrowed value (my_attr) doesn't live long enough.

It makes sense, so for instance the following does indeed compile:

```
struct List<'a> {
    attr: &'a String
}

impl<'a> List<'a> {
    fn new(my_attr: &'a String) -> List<'a> {
        List {
            attr: my_attr
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_attr = "Something".to_string();
    List::new(&my_attr);
}
```

However, I like the first form more, especially from an encapsulation stand point.

Is it possible to create and also assign a reference to a value from within the new method (as per the failing example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that a `&'a String` is a borrowed value - that is, it is a reference to a value that is stored elsewhere. On your first example, that "elsewhere" is the `new` function stack, and on the second it's `main`'s stack.

You don't get an error on the second case because `main`'s lifetime is bigger than your `List`'s lifetime - that is, the `List` will die before `main` finishes. That is not the case of your first scenario, where the `List` is returned by `new`, and thus the reference is invalid.

The solution here is to make `List` own its `String`, instead of just taking a reference to it. This way, `List`'s lifetime isn't linked to anything else.

```
struct List {
    attr: String,
}

impl List {
    fn new() -> List {
        let my_attr = "Something";

        List {
            attr: my_attr.to_string()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is just an abstraction, String is actually a File handler in my original code. I really want to use &String.

Comment: Why do you want to use a reference? Is your `File` shared between multiple structs?